# Android: Measured width of dynamically created TextView sometimes wrong

Tags: android

I'm stuck on a strange little problem.

The goal with this activity is to display two texts, one is the original the second the answer text. The answer text contains errors and the user has to find and mark those errors.
The solution we came up with is to split the text into its words and display each word as its own in a TextView. All these TextViews are created dynamically at runtime, because there are many different texts to display.
There are two instances, where we need a 'line break': a) the text contains a linebreak (
) and b) the width of the display wouldn't fit any more text.

This solution works most of the time but each text has 2-4 words, which don't fit the line width and are therefore broken up into multiple lines visually.

Here's the code:

```java
String[] questionSplit = exercise.exerciseQuestion.split(" ");
ids = new Integer[questionSplit.length];
int displayWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
int currentLineWidth = 0;
Integer lastIdInRow = 0;
int counter = 0;
for(String bit : questionSplit) {
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setId(generateViewId());
    ids[counter] = tv.getId();

    //Exception for <br>
    if(bit.equals("<br>")) {
        lastIdInRow = ids[counter - 1];
        currentLineWidth = 0;
    } else {
        tv.setText(bit);
        tv.setPadding(dpToPx(3), dpToPx(3), dpToPx(2), dpToPx(2));
        tv.measure(0, 0);
        currentLineWidth += tv.getMeasuredWidth();
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        if(currentLineWidth <= displayWidth && counter == 0) {
            // move along, nothing to see here
        } else if(currentLineWidth <= displayWidth && counter != 0) {
            p.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, ids[counter - 1]);
        } else {
            lastIdInRow = ids[counter - 1];
            currentLineWidth = 0;
        }

        if(lastIdInRow != 0 && lastIdInRow != tv.getId()) {
            p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, lastIdInRow);
        }

        rlTextComparisonOriginal.addView(tv,p);
    }

    counter++;
}
```

To explain the layout rules of the TextViews: if the measuredWidth fits into the line, a RIGHT_OF the last id rule is added. If it would overflow, a BELOW the last id in the line rule is added.
As I mentioned earlier, for most of the text that works perfectly. But there are some words which do not fit. If I change the displayWidth to be only 80% of the display width, the error persists just the word changes, so I think it's not the specific text / word.

And here is the relevant part of the view's xml

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/svTextComparisonDesc"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/tvTextComparisonHeaderMiddle"
    android:paddingBottom="55dp"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlTextComparison"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTextComparisonDescription"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/text_background"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/text_exercise_desription"
            android:textSize="@dimen/activity_text_description_size"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlTextComparisonOriginal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/text_background"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvTextComparisonDescription"
            />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlTextComparisonAnswer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/rlTextComparisonOriginal"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The last bit of information: right now the code above resides in the activity's onCreate Method. If I log the measuredWidth and displayWidth and currentWidth, the logic isn't broken, the measuredWidth fits into the line, but after rendering, it doesn't.

Any ideas what the problem actually might be? Thanks in advance!

After using the mentioned lib the code is much cleaner and looks like this:

```
//Exception for <br>
if(bit.equals("<br>")) {
    FlowLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FlowLayout.LayoutParams(0,0);
    lp.setNewLine(true);
    flTextComparisonOriginal.addView(tv,lp);
} else {
    tv.setText(bit);
    tv.setPadding(dpToPx(3), dpToPx(3), dpToPx(2), dpToPx(2));
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    flTextComparisonOriginal.addView(tv, p);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case using a library is acceptable instead of coding it yourself, you will find two projects on github under the keyword "FlowLayout". These sound like they solve the layout you need:

https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout

https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout

Comment: Perfect, thank you!
I used this lib [link](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout)

Answer (score 0):

To get width and height of the text view,

```
Rect bounds = new Rect();
Paint textPaint = textView.getPaint();
textPaint.getTextBounds(text,0,text.length(),bounds);
int height = bounds.height();
int width = bounds.width();
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem. The width only uses the text, not the paddings.

Comment: just add textView.getPaddingLeft() and  textView.getPaddingRight() to width